# How to preprocessing params when model create in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have form and pass params:

```
user_params = { first_name: "Bob", last_name: "A" }
```

I have a `User` model which has field `full_name`, `first_name`, `short_name`

So when the params pass to controller, and I call:

```
@user = User.create(user_params)
```

I want to store the user with full_name = Bob A, first_name = Bob, short_name = "B.A". Is it possible? If not, where is the best place to transfer the params? `before_action` in controller?

The key problem is that the form params have different structure with database schema. So a transforming required.

Comment: For what purpose `full_name` should be stored? Do you need to search by `full_name` or use it somehow?

Comment: @Yakov, no purpose, just for example. In real world, it's not `full_name`. It represents a new field which created based on the data of form params.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer extracting this logic into a separate class. I call them "param objects".

```rb
# controller
def create
  @user = User.create(ParamObjects::User::Create.new(params).call)
  ...
end

# the param object
module ParamObjects::User
  class Create
    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end 

    def call
      { 
        first_name: params[:first_name],
        full_name: compute_full_name,
        short_name: compute_short_name,
      }
    end

    private

    attr_reader :params
    
    def compute_full_name  
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But if you're looking for something simpler, Yakov has outlined a couple good options.

Comment: You know, this is a good idea, but it does make things quite a bit more verbose. However, I really do like the separation of concerns. One other thing you could do is make it a [Concern](https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/09/16/rails-concers-to-concern-or-not-to-concern.html). I do much of my parameter preprocessing this way, which helps me to generalize some of this behavior and abstract it out to not duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

There might be different ways to do it.

Create a method inside a controller:

```
def prepared_user_params
  user_params.merge(
    full_name: "#{user_params[:first_name]} #{user_params[:short_name]}"
  )
end
```

Then you can use this method `@user = User.create(prepared_user_params)`.

Or use a callback inside `User` model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_full_name

  private
 
  def set_full_name
    self.full_name = "#{first_name} #{short_name}"
  end
end
```

So, after you call `User.create(user_params)`, `first_name` and `first_name` get assigned, `full_name` gets set by a callback.

Also, it's possible to use some service class that does all the preparations.

Comment: The model method is preferable imo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When using the set method, how to set up validation method for `full_name`? For example, `validates_presence_of`

Comment: `before_save` can be replaced by `before_validation` callback. Then you can apply any validation to it.

Comment: `self.full_name = [first_name, short_name].reject(&:blank?).join(' ')` to make presence validation works properly.